# ng-hide not working inside button Ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view, ng-hide

```
<button class="footer-bar-item item-right button button-clear" ng-hide="taskDetails.task_id == '2044'">
    <button class="button" ng-click="addNote(taskDetails.task_id)">Add Note</button>
</button>
```

> taskDetails.task_id value is String and its value is equal to "2044".But button not hides.I'm new to Ionic.I'll grateful if someone can help me to resolve this.

Comment: are you binding the $scope.taskDetails.task_id variable properly in your component and check in console if it changes to 2044 after you click on adNote()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found solution.

```
 <button class="footer-bar-item item-right button button-clear" >
        <button ng-hide="taskDetails.task_id == '2044'" class="button" ng-click="addNote(taskDetails.task_id)">Add Note {{taskDetails.task_id == '2044'}}</button>
    </button>
```

Comment: mark this answer as correct if it was the one which solved the problem, so future readers know it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet, those quotation marks aren't parsable.

Change

```
ng-hide=”taskDetails.task_id == '2044'”
```

to

```
ng-hide="taskDetails.task_id == '2044'"
```

Comment: Hi David,
I changed that one but it did not hide still.any suggestions for that.

Comment: try debugging by using {{ taskDetails.task_id == '2044' }} in a <div> tag and seeing if thats true or false.

Comment: to follow-up, is there any reason you have a button inside a button? Perhaps the outside tag should be changed to a div.